# Combine OSGi blueprint and spring configuration

Tags: spring, osgi, spring-dm, blueprint-osgi

Are there any good/best practices regarding the combination of Spring configuration and OSGi Blueprint (e.g. Gemini Blueprint)? Which XML files do you use? Where do you put them in your OSGi bundles (`META-INF/spring`, `OSGi-INF`)? Which of these practices will allow you to reuse your bundles in combination with a non-Gemini-implementation of Blueprint?

Background: We are in the process of switching from Spring/Spring DM to Spring/Blueprint. I am aware of Blueprint defining a `<bean>` element. However we occasionally face the situation that the limited bean definition capabilities of the Blueprint specification do not meet all our needs. So it seems to be a good choice to use Spring configuration within our bundles and Blueprint for wiring bundles via OSGi services.

Comment: very good question

Answer (score 13):

> Which XML files do you use? Where do you put them in your OSGi bundles
>   (META-INF/spring, OSGi-INF)? Which of these practices will allow you
>   to reuse your bundles in combination with a non-Gemini-implementation
>   of Blueprint?

Gemini Blueprint treats both of these directories equally, but **`OSGI-INF/blueprint/*.xml` is the only one specified in the generic OSGi Blueprint specification.**

A suggested practice from [the Gemini Blueprint documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/1.0.2.RELEASE/html/app-deploy.html#app-deploy%3aheaders) is:

> [...] A
>   suggested practice is to split the application context configuration
>   into at least two files, named by convention modulename-context.xml
>   and modulename-osgi-context.xml. The modulename-context.xml file
>   contains regular bean definitions independent of any knowledge of
>   OSGi. The modulename-osgi-context.xml file contains the bean
>   definitions for importing and exporting OSGi services. It may (but is
>   not required to) use the Gemini Blueprint OSGi schema as the top-level
>   namespace instead of the Spring 'beans' namespace.

I tried this, and it works great. I use Gemini Blueprint for one of my projects which has the files `META-INF/spring/context.xml`, which defines my beans and their relationships, and `META-INF/spring/osgi-context.xml`, which defines which beans to expose as/import from OSGi services and how. `context.xml` looks like

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
    <bean id="myOrdinarySpringBean" class="com.acme.impl.Foo"/>
</beans>
```

and is a regular ordinary Spring application context with no Blueprint/OSGi configuration at all. `osgi-context.xml` looks like

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
    <service id="myOsgiService" ref="myOrdinarySpringBean" interface="com.acme.Foo"/>
</blueprint>
```

You could, of course, use the `<beans>` namespace and root element here as well, but you'd have to define a `xmlns:osgi` and prefix the service like so: `<osgi:service .../>` for that to work. In my case I don't need the Gemini specific Blueprint stuff, so I'm happy with this generic Blueprint configuration. Likewise, I could use the `<blueprint>` namespace in `context.xml` as well, but this particular application is an old one being ported to OSGi, so I prefer to keep that configuration Spring specific for now.

Another application in turn has its own `osgi-context.xml` like

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
  <reference id="myOrdinarySpringBeanImportedFromOsgi" interface="com.acme.Foo" availability="mandatory"/>
</blueprint>
```

and at this time doesn't, but could, have its own `context.xml` like

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
    <bean id="myOrdinaryOtherSpringBean" class="com.acme.impl.Bar">
        <property name="foo" ref="myOrdinarySpringBeanImportedFromOsgi"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and couldn't really care less whether `myOrdinarySpringBeanImportedFromOsgi` is imported from an OSGi service or defined as a regular ordinary Spring bean in the same application context.

These `META-INF/osgi-context.xml` configurations could trivially be moved to `OSGI-INF/blueprint/` if I want to decouple yourself from the Gemini Blueprint implementation, but for the time being I prefer to keep the two halves in the same place to avoid making a mess of the directory structure.

Comment: hi @Emil Lundberg is it mandatory to use xml based configuration while defining spring appication context

Comment: @jayantmishra Sorry, I don't know - I haven't really touched Spring or OSGi since I wrote this 5 years ago.

Comment: This is a great answer and I am extremely thankful to you

Answer (score 5):

Blueprint files should go under OSGI-INF/blueprint/ and are named *.xml (typically blueprint.xml).  This location is per the OSGi 4.2 Blueprint spec and will work with Aries or Gemini.

Spring-DM files (as you probably know) go under META-INF/spring/ and are also named *.xml (typically beans.xml)

Both files should be able to peacefully co-exist.  They'll only work, though, if you have support for each container installed.

Wiring should be done via the OSGi Service Registry.

As for migration, we have stayed on Spring-DM for capabilities that we couldn't do in Blueprint.  Everything else has been migrated to Blueprint.

Comment: I don't think it works in JBoss Fuse. Imported service in Aries OSGi xml cannot be recognized in Spring DM xml.

Comment: I don't think you can expose and consume a service from the same bundle.  This is not a blueprint/spring interoperability problem.  The same problem will happen with just spring or just blueprint.

Comment: @mjmeno is it mandatory to define xml based config for spring application context, or annotation based will also do?

Comment: @jayantmishra I'm not sure, I don't know of anywhere that's been done on projects I contribute to.  Some searching returned https://docs.spring.io/spring-osgi/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-extensions.html which implies it might be possible.

Comment: @mjmeno thanks for the pointer, will try it out n let you knw